# CharacterController & Collisions issue?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, character, collision-detection

In Runner Game I need to detected collions with Objects. I use CharacterController and OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class mainPlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{   
    void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
    {
        print(hit.gameObject.name);
    }
}
```

But, if my character collide with some object in front of it - no collision detected! What'd the problem?

P.s. In the game I use the method: my Character always stay. All world moves around it. Is it the best way?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you moved `transform.position`. use `CharacterController.Move()` instead.

```
Controller.Move(SomeMotion * Time.deltaTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onControllerColliderHit` only gets called if the controller collides with something while moving using the `Charactercontroller.Move()` function. Since your character never moves this won't be called.

If you still want the world to move you could try and use a raycast with set max distance to check if something is in front of your player.

Comment: I use CharacterController.move(), but only for horizontal movement. For forward/Back movement Vector.Direction always 0. But collisions aren't detected. Should I use RayCast then?

Comment: As long as the move function is being called, it should detect collisions with other colliders. You could try and use a raycast and see if it fits your needs.